# jquery radio button value not working when there are more than one

Tags: jquery, radio-button, formwizard

I use jquery for my form. My form has got lots of radion button types of questions.

```
<div>
        <label>1) Competently cut paper with scissors?</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_165607" id="CAT_Custom_165607_0" value="Yes" />
            Yes
            <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_165607" id="CAT_Custom_165607_1" value="No" />
            No
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>2) Hold a pencil in a mature pencil grip? </label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_165609" id="CAT_Custom_165609_0" value="Yes" />
            Yes
            <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_165609" id="CAT_Custom_165609_1" value="No" />
            No
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>3) Write his/her first name - recognisable? </label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_165610" id="CAT_Custom_165610_0" value="Yes" />
            Yes
            <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_165610" id="CAT_Custom_165610_1" value="No" />
            No
    </div>
```

And I have my jquery function here:

```
function checkWholeForm(){
      var q1 = $('input[@name="CAT_Custom_165607"]:checked').val();
      var q2 = $('input[@name="CAT_Custom_165609"]:checked').val();
      var q3 = $('input[@name="CAT_Custom_165610"]:checked').val();
      alert(q2);
      return false;
       }
```

When I chose no, yes, yes for the three questions. It always alerts "No", which is the value of q1. But I tried alert the value of q2. Same result when I alerted q3. Anything clashes here? Cheers.

Comment: At what point do you call `checkWholeForm()`?

Comment: Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the “@” symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again.

Answer (score 3):

You're using wrong syntax for attribute selector. The right syntax is

```
'input[name="CAT_Custom_165607"]:checked'
```

Notice, no `@`

Answer (score 0):

With recent jQuery versions you can also do the following, which finds the selected input and returns the value.

`$('input[name=CAT_Custom_165610]').val()`

Additionally, do not validate in Javascript unless it's only for aesthetics. It can be bypassed. Always validate in your backend code, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please try this code.

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
alert($(this).val());
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/sMbhM/1/)

I hope It will works for you.